# How do I use tableview to navigate to new view/page/screen

Tags: view, tableview

So I have use tableview to make a list that works with the search bar, but now I want the sections in the tableview to navigate/go to a new view/page/screen when I press it, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] animated:YES];
 }
```